# ¿Por qué no obtengo el campo user_id en la consulta con ambos Joins?

Tags: laravel

Tengo un buscador, el mismo hace la consulta en unas tablas y funciona bien, exceptuando que no me trae el `user_id` (Muestra un valor `NULL`) a menos que suba una foto (Haga uso del join de `Photo`).

```
public function searchEmployer(Request $request)
{
    $results = User::where('user_type', 'Employer')
                        ->join('offers', 'offers.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                        ->join('photos', 'photos.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                        ->search($request)
                        ->paginate(25);
                        dd($results);
                        
    return view('web.search', compact('results'));
}
```

Migración:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('offers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id('id');
        $table->foreignId('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreignId('frequency_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('frequency_id')->references('id')->on('frequencies');
        $table->foreignId('hour_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('hour_id')->references('id')->on('hours');
        $table->foreignId('per_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('per_id')->references('id')->on('per');
        $table->text('summary')->nullable();
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->date('start_date')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Lo que me devuelve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Posiblemente se estén superponiendo las columnas de las dos tablas que haces join. Deberías agregar un select con las columnas de cada tabla que quieres que te devuelva, y asignar un alias a las que tienen el mismo nombre, por ej 'id', 'user_id', 'created_at', etc

Comment: Gracias @porloscerros

Comment: Gracias Juan, las preguntas son diferentes.

Comment: reemplaza por righJoin, obviamente el id es ambiguo ya que no que estas especificando en el select, mysql por defecto puede traer cualquier id de las tablas, como no encuentra la relación te va traer null el id